# table in html to take up all of screen, one column bigger than other

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I basically want to create a login page, one side of the page saying login, and he other saying register. I was thinking of doing it by implementing a 2 column table. This is what I have for html:

```
    <table width = 100% border= "1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class = 'login' >
                Login 
                <form action="demo_form.asp" >
                    Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br/>
                    Password: <input type="text" id="password"><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class = 'register'>
                    Register
                    <form action="demo_form.asp">
                    First Name: <input type="text" id="first"><br>
                    Last Name: <input type="text" id="last"><br>
                    Username: <input type="text" id="newuser"><br>
                    Password: <input type="text" id="newpassword"><br>
                    Confirm Password: <input type="text" id="newpassword"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

however even though i set the width of the table to be 100% of the screen I can see because I added a border that the column to right is bigger than the column to the left. Why is that and how do I fix it? This is a side note but also how would I make my input fields align, like all be at the same position, right now it looks very ugly. I would apprciate any help!

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this with a table?

Comment: no particular reason, if there is an easier way feel free to enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

I just hate tables (as many people do) and feel they died out for a reason and feel modern html css is a much more solid route. This is just off the top of my head but should get you what you want. You also mentioned you want to get your content centered, here is a good article on a few different techniques. http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left_col">

  </div>
  <div class="right_col">

  </div>
</div>

html, body, .wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.left_col{
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.right_col{
 height:100%;
 width:50%;
 float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To line your input fields up you simply need to put all your text into `<span>` and then use that to set the width in which the next object can be displayed. So it should look something like this.

### Your HTML

```
<span>Login</span> 
<form action="demo_form.asp" >
    <span>Username: </span><input type="text" id="username"><br/>
    <span>Password: </span><input type="text" id="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### Your CSS

```
span{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Another thing i would recommend is using labels, just a quick search should enlighten it to you.